# Process encountered symbols while also having access to a SemanticModel in Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, analyzer

in a Roslyn Analyzer project, I want to flag all symbols marked with a particular attribute. For example, if the symbol is a method, then I want this method (or rather, its definition, although this distinction is not so relevant because [`GetAttributes`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Symbols/Symbol_Attributes.cs,22) gives me what I need anyways) to be checked for this attribute anywhere it is invoked or even simply used without any direct invocation (such as in a method group). Likewise, I would want any references (variable declaration, cast, type parameter, return type, etc.) to a certain (named) type to be checked to see if the type is decorated with the corresponding attribute.

Now, I thought I could get away with simply registering a symbol action using [`RegisterSymbolAction`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/DiagnosticStartAnalysisScope.cs#49) on `AnalysisContext`, but the thing is that, while I have the ability to break on symbols directly (without doing any syntax manipulation), I do not have a `SemanticModel` to interpret the symbols I find, as it is not on the `SymbolAnalysisContext` type. This means that I cannot even check if the attribute is of the right type, let alone do any other related comparative operation.

Now, from what I have gathered from the source code, the semantic model is not guaranteed to be valid when a call to the handler method that is provided to `RegisterSymbolAction` is invoked for a particular symbol (since it might not even have finished building yet). That being said, is there a way to actually be provided with a symbol (or at least a collection of encountered symbols) and a corresponding valid semantic model at the same time ? What I am trying to avoid, if I can, is to be forced to go through a whole syntax tree (most probably obtained from a `SemanticModelAnalysisContext`) and to interpret each and every node to its potential symbol equivalent.

I am not saying that it is not a valid solution, I am just looking for a potential alternative that I do not know about. I was maybe thinking of something along the lines of `CompilationAnalysisContext` or `CodeBlockAnalysisContext`, but so far, I've had no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to get access to a `SemanticModel` from `SymbolAnalysisContext`?

On the [`Compilation`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/DiagnosticAnalyzer/DiagnosticAnalysisContext.cs,4a6db38bdb8adc56,references) property you can use [`GetSemanticModel()`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Compilation/Compilation.cs,53e11cf29c3c4036,references) and pass in the syntax tree of the symbol you're looking at.

```
private static void AnalyzeSymbol(SymbolAnalysisContext context)
{
    var compilation = context.Compilation;
    var syntax = context.Symbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences.First(); //Careful, partial methods might burn you
    var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntax.SyntaxTree);
    //Use your model however you please!
}
```

Comment: I guess that I could go the `DeclaringSyntaxReferences` way, but, as you mentioned, partial methods could put some rain on my parade. Also, I have the feeling that `DeclaringSyntaxReferences` might not be the lightest operation performance-wise (I might be wrong on that), and I would be calling it for every symbol the analyzer encounters. Good alternative though. I'd be curious to know if it's more worthwhile than going though the syntax tree and getting the symbols.

Comment: The rule of thumb seems to be if it's not marked `async` it shouldn't be too expensive for an analyzer. `DeclaringSyntaxReferences` in particular is a property which leads me to believe we can expect good performance out of it.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't noticed that it was a property. I just looked as the source code, and it does not seem that bad. I'll still leave the question open to see if any else has any more ideas, but otherwise I'll probably end up going the way you proposed.